# Using urandom in windows

Tags: python, security, random

What happens when you use os.urandom(256) in python in windows ?

The code shows :

```
def urandom(n):
    """urandom(n) -> str

    Return a string of n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.

    """
    try:
        _urandomfd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)
    except (OSError, IOError):
        raise NotImplementedError("/dev/urandom (or equivalent) not found")
    try:
        bs = b""
        while n > len(bs):
            bs += read(_urandomfd, n - len(bs))
    finally:
        close(_urandomfd)
    return bs
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom says when it is run in Windows it automatically uses `CryptGenRandom()`. I cannot find references to this implementation anywhere.

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1166b3321012/Python/random.c#l40

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx