# How do I determine what PRNG python.random is using?

Tags: python, random

I'm looking for more information about `random`. Primarily what was the seed and how many steps have happened in that pseudo random sequence & Was that seed a datetime, i.e. did random use the system provided random or default to time?

I looked at dir(random) and didn't see anything super promising...

Comment: None of that information is tracked, and none can be inferred from the current state.

Comment: Not what I want to hear but I appreciate the response... How can random operate without any information existing?

Comment: @TimPeters Do you know how likely it is on today's computers that the urandom seeding fails? And I guess that could be tested with almost certainty by adding some logging into the source code and running the same code again?

Comment: @KellyBundy What is there to log?

Comment: @kpie Whether the urandom seeding succeeded.

Comment: CPython uses the Mersenne Twister, which has a quite large internal state. So it remembers a whole lot from one call to the next. But it remembers nothing whatsoever about the _history_ of how it got to its current state. About urandom seeding failing, in a deep sense it doesn't matter: your application is insane if it's using `Random` for crypto-strength programs regardless. Those should be using `SystemRandom` instead.

Comment: @TimPeters Well, for some reason it seems to matter to the OP (see their [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71432826/12671057)), although they ignored my question about why.

Comment: @KellyBundy on Windows there's no urandom, but Python provides a suitable substitute.  See e.g. [Using urandom in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21762753/5987).

Comment: @KellyBundy, ;yes, seems like an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @MarkRansom That's over 8 years old, is it still the case?

Comment: @KellyBundy, adding logging and running the same code again is most likely useless. _If_ urandom (or a different platform workalike) _can_ fail at all, it's likely because the OS doesn't think there's enough "entropy" yet to satisfy the request, and a non-blocking call was made.  Very rare, if possible at all, and almost certainly not reproducible (in the absence of a platform bug).

Comment: @KellyBundy there's a comment there that links to the C code used by Python.  Not sure if the link points to the most current code, but it certainly gives a good starting point if you wanted to investigate for yourself.  I doubt that Python would regress on such an important function.

Comment: @MarkRansom Actually I think we're talking about different urandoms. I mean `os.urandom` (and `_PyOS_URandomNonblock`), which do exist for Windows as well. I'm not talking about /dev/urandom.

Comment: @MarkRansom, ;indeed, changes in this area are debated far beyond the bounds of human endurance among Python's core devs ;-)

Comment: There don't seem to be that many methods, you could easily write your own class that's basically a wrapper but counts invocations and saves the seed and the method used to generate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) states:

> Almost all module functions depend on the basic function random(),
> which generates a random float uniformly in the semi-open range [0.0,
> 1.0). Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces 53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1. The
> underlying implementation in C is both fast and threadsafe. The
> Mersenne Twister is one of the most extensively tested random number
> generators in existence. However, being completely deterministic, it
> is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for
> cryptographic purposes.

You can study the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/random.py), in particular the [default implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4199b7ffbbaa5fe52a4c85c8672ac6773a75ba8f/Lib/random.py#L103) "seeds from current time or from an operating system specific randomness source if available"

Comment: That particular part is **not** there.

Comment: What particular part?

Comment: The part the quote is talking about, using urandom or time and pid. It's in the C code.

Comment: Yeah I think it's https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/204946986feee7bc80b233350377d24d20fcb1b8/Modules/_randommodule.c

Comment: So is there like a numerical seed I can get somehow? I know a can do random.seed(time.time()) can I then do like random.getseed().asint()

Comment: The closest I can see is to call random.getstate() [I've not tested this], it's not the seed though
 (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4199b7ffbbaa5fe52a4c85c8672ac6773a75ba8f/Lib/random.py#L170)

Comment: @kpie there's nothing in `random` that keeps the seed value.  If you need to know how it was seeded, you need to seed it yourself and keep the value yourself.